# How to reference button for onClickListener?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I am trying to create an Android app, and i want to create a on click listener, here is what I have so far.

```
public void amazonListener() {
amazonButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.amazonButton);                
}
```

As you see, i am in the very early stages, but where I first referenced *amazonButton* (before the = sign) button, it turns into red text and it says  *Cannot resolve symbol 'amazonButton'*. Also, I have referenced this method in the onCreate method

Comment: Try `JButton amazonButton = ...`. You need to say what type amazon button is.

Comment: Now it shows the same error on 'JButton'

Comment: Did you import the `JButton` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you'd go about creating a button and setting a click listener to it.

```
public class MainActivity extends YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity {

    Button amazonButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        amazonButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.amazonButton);
        amazonButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Define what should happen when the button is clicked. 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can also put the initializations in a single method and call that method, like you've tried :

```
public class MainActivity extends YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity {

    Button amazonButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initializeViews();
    }

    private void initializeViews() {
        //Make sure you've declared the buttons before you initialize them. 
        amazonButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.amazonButton);
        amazonButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Define what should happen when the button is clicked. 
            }
        });

        // Add more Views initialization here ...
        ....
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the type of the variable when you declare it.

```
Button amazonButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.amazonButton);
```

The alternative is to declare it (but not initialize it) outside of any method and then initialize it later.

```
Button amazonButton;
/* ... */
private void amazonListener() { 
    amazonButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.amazonButton);                
}
```